# What is the bucket list in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, poa

I get the error below when starting my PoA network. I have no idea what defines a bucket list. Has anyone more details?

> DEBUG[06-01|10:58:47] Found seed node in database
>   id=ed8b3be93192299f addr=35.197.215.1 21:30311 age=42m41.092986442s
>   DEBUG[06-01|10:58:47] IP exceeds bucket limit
>   ip=35.197.215.121 DEBUG[06-01|10:58:47] IP exceeds bucket limit
>   ip=35.197.215.121 DEBUG[06-01|10:58:47] Found seed node in database
>   id=a332d3b08042bf20 addr=35.197.215.1 21:30312 age=42m39.093013259s
>   DEBUG[06-01|10:58:47] IP exceeds bucket limit
>   ip=35.197.215.121 DEBUG[06-01|10:58:47] IP exceeds bucket limit
>   ip=35.197.215.121 DEBUG[06-01|10:58:47] Found seed node in database
>   id=9d0c4f3a797807ae addr=35.197.215.1 21:30315 age=42m44.093043253s
>   DEBUG[06-01|10:58:47] IP exceeds bucket limit
>   ip=35.197.215.121 DEBUG[06-01|10:58:47] IP exceeds bucket limit

Answer (score 2):

A bucket list is a list of things you'd like to do before you die, such as getting a private PoA network up and running.

A bucket *limit* is an upper bound for the number of peer IP addresses that your client can handle in any given "bucket" while running its peer discovery mechanisms.

From the code, it looks like the limit is set to 2 peers from the same `/24` subnet.

From [`p2p/discover/table.go.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/9fd76e33af367752160ab0e33d1097e1e9aff6e4/p2p/discover/table.go#L53):

```
// IP address limits.
bucketIPLimit, bucketSubnet = 2, 24 // at most 2 addresses from the same /24
tableIPLimit, tableSubnet   = 10, 24
```

I'm not familiar enough with this bit of code to suggest a proper solution, but the above might be an indication of where to look further.

Note, however, that this is only a `DEBUG` level message, not an `ERROR`. By reducing the verbosity of Geth's output you could probably safely ignore the message.

```
if !b.ips.Add(ip) {
    log.Debug("IP exceeds bucket limit", "ip", ip)
```

Comment: The PoA network is running but it is not stable - a bit like the US economy.